# Is a 128GB SSD large enough for two operating systems?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I need an SSD for the following things:

- Windows 10
- Ubuntu (as a parallel system to choose after switching on the computer)
- NetBeans IDE
- local PHP (XAMPP) server + project files

Is a 128GB large enough for those? I'd probably have to create multiple partitions for the two operating systems.

Comment: "How long is a piece of string?" It really depends on what you want to store on it, and what you install.

Comment: The real question is - won't these systems get too large in time by themselves?

Comment: Lemme give you an example. My base win 10 installs are under 15gb. My current windows install is ~80gb on my gaming box. I do need to clean it up tho. I have installs however that sit comfortably on a 32 gb drive as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50GB is for each operating system will do, but you would be well advised to have a second conventional hard drive as well to use for other storing data exclusive of your project files. Your project files can be stored on either partition, see [How to read ext4 partitions on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows) and [How to mount read-write an ext4 partition on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/465393/how-to-mount-read-write-an-ext4-partition-on-windows).

SSDs slow down over time as they're filled up. You will need to keep 10-25% of the SSD empty for fast performance depending on the model of the SSD.

Comment: But the problem is that - ssd will probably have 115gb available, and 25-30gb has to be left empty.

Comment: @KarolHernik: Ermm, why?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq You will need to keep 25 percent of ssd empty for fast functioning

Answer (score 0):

It will be enough. A time ago I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu on 120 GB drive (25 GB partition for Windows, 10 (system) + 2 (swap) for Ubuntu, rest for the data).