# Manualy Clean Second Partition In Android Link2SD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, android, ext4

I use Link2SD in my Android Phone to link some of my apps into external second partition.
My external total size is 32GB and I partition it into 2 partition. **First Partition is using FAT32**, and **the second is using EXT4 for 6GB**.
And now my Second partition free space is almost full. I already clean 2nd partition using LINK2SD feature but still not working. And I think some of junk files is still there (the 2nd partition).

Is any way to access that 2nd partition and I can see what inside, so that I can manualy clean the junk files?

(I'm using Windows 10 for my Primary Oprating System. I'm not yet try access the 2nd partition using Linux)

**note:**
*I try to use **[Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)** but the 2nd partition file system is can't be access, and can't be mounted.*

Answer (score -1):

I found it.

Ref1: [How to read ext4 partitions on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows)

Ref2: [How to mount read-write an ext4 partition on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/465393/how-to-mount-read-write-an-ext4-partition-on-windows)

And I use this software: https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/