# Paragon ExtFS can't write files to Ext4 drive from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, ext4

Windows 10 Home version 1607 64-bit

Product link: http://www.paragon-drivers.com/extfs-windows/

I seem to be able to read files but I can't *write* files. I get the error:

> An unexpected error is keeping you from copying the file. If you
>   continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search
>   for help with this problem.
>
> Error 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.

None of the "Read-only" checkboxes are checked, they're all cleared.

Also, Explorer (my taskbar and such) crashes sometimes when I try to write a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it as follows:
I uninstalled all 3rd party software like Ext2Fsd, ext2explore, etc.

I cleaned the registry, restarted and paragon extfs is now working. It's copying files to Linux HDD at 100mb/s.

Comment: Can you still remember what that "I cleaned the registry" specifically meant? Especially in the context that your solution didn't seem to involve also reinstalling Paragon then. Thx!